# How do i get the username of a logged user writing a text and display it beside the text permanently in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Please see the image, I want to add the name of the person entering the text at the end of the text.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd5fn.png
Here is my code for the template.
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Topic: {{ topic }}</p>
  
  <p>Entries:</p>
  <p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}">add new entry</a>
  </p>
  <ul>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
      <b><p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p></b>
      <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}">edit entry</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>
      There are no entries for this topic yet.
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  

{% endblock content %}
```

Here is my views function for the topic:

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its enteries"""
    topic= Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries= topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context= {'topic': topic, 'entries':entries}
    user_if= request.user
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

Here are my Topic and Entry models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic user is learning about"""
    text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    
    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
         return self.text[:50] +"..."
       
class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about the topic"""
    topic=models.ForeignKey('Topic',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text=models.TextField()
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of model"""
        return self.text[:50] +"..."
```

I want to add the name of the person entering the text beside the text, I have the username and password of the users stored in the database but I don't know how to display the name of the user permanently beside the text. It is just like comments where the users have their names above the comment. Do tell me if the question wants more code display, I will add the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to dynamically show the user while writing the text. You should then pass request.user in context so that current user who is editing will always be available in the template.

```
context = {"topic": topic, "entries": entries, "current_user":request.user}
```

Now since current_user is available in the template just use it inside the template

```
@{{current_user.username}}
```

If you are saving the username otherwise show whichever field you want to for eg. current_user.full_name

Answer (score 0):

You can always write {{request.user.username}} at any point you want the logged in user's username to appear.

No need to pass the user object as extra context.